# Can't cite all authors in the first citation with R Markdown (output Word)

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, citations, pandoc-citeproc

I'm writing a paper using R Markdown for the first time. Here are my YAML options

```
---
title: "My path to the Nobel"
author: "J.E. Alcalá"
lang: english
bibliography: data_analysis.bib
csl: apa.csl
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: apa_template.docx
---
```

When I cite a paper for the firs time it doesn't show all authors. For example `[e.g., @maei2009]` should display (e.g., Maei, Zaslavsky, & Wang 2009) the first time I cite that paper, but instead I get (e.g., Maei et al. 2009). Probably is something stupid but I'm really new on R Markdown, so I don't even know where to look for an answer (despite I have tried).

An answer or a reference to how fix this will be very useful.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to xhange citation style for that to change.

Comment: @DrorBogin I'm using the apa.csl, do you mean I need to do _something else_ to change that?

Comment: The apa citation style uses **et al** when there are more than two authors. You could use a different citation style if you want to keep all the author names.

Comment: @DrorBogin It's a clear instruction in the APA Publications Manual (6° ed) to use all the authors surnames (>3) in the first citation and just the first author in subsequent citations (p. 175). Hence my question says "the first..."

Comment: `apa.csl` is not necessarily `apa.csl`, try different ones till it fits to your needs, or consult [citation styles editor](http://editor.citationstyles.org/about/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CSL style for APA 6th edition](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/apa.csl) follows the APA guidelines for et-al abbreviation (which are discussed [here](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/apa_style/apa_formatting_and_style_guide/in_text_citations_author_authors.html) and [here](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/11/the-proper-use-of-et-al-in-apa-style.html)), and only uses "et al." for first citations when there are more than 6 authors.

I tried to locate the article for "Maei, Zaslavsky, & Wang 2009" in your example, and the only 2009 article with these three initial authors seems to be "Development and validation of a sensitive entropy-based measure for the water maze" (https://doi.org/10.3389/neuro.07.033.2009), by Maei HR, Zaslavsky K, Wang AH, Yiu AP, Teixeira CM, Josselyn SA, and Frankland PW. That's 7 authors, in which case APA requires et-al abbreviation with just the first author shown. Could this explain the unexpected result?